# Dropping sprite it's "weapon" to the world without sprite having instance of the world

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, tile

I'm currently busy creating a game where the instance should be able to drop items to the form. So let's say "Aircraft" has an instance of "gun". My question then would be : How can I make the Ship drop his gun so the Gun will be moved from Ship to the world.

My game isn't tile based, else i could just say `Tile.interact(givegun)` but now that the ship doesn't have something to interact with, how can ship drop its weapon to the world.

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to tell and I would appreciate a little bit of help.

//Main class - Initialise

```
        MovableObject playerShip = new Ship(Content, settings);
        movableObjects.Add(playerShip);
```

//Shipe class - Update method

```
    public override Param.Param Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < availableBullets.Count; i++)
        {
            availableBullets[i].Update(gameTime);
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            if (Position.Y > 0)
                Position.Y -= speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            if(Position.Y < settings.Height - texture.Height)
            Position.Y += speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            if (Position.X > 0)
                Position.X -= speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            if (Position.X < settings.Width - texture.Width)
                Position.X += speed;
        }

        if (shootSpeed > 0)
        {
            shootSpeed--;
        }

        if (shootSpeed == 0)
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                shootSpeed = 10;
                return fire();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

//Ship class - Fire method

```
    public Param.Param fire()
    {
        Param.Param shipItemParam = null;

        if (availableBullets.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < availableBullets.Count; i++)
            {
                Param.Param ShipInteractBullet = new ShipInteractBullet(this.Position, ShipEnum.FIRE);
                availableBullets[i].Interact(ShipInteractBullet);
                shipItemParam = new ShipDropItem(availableBullets[i]);
                availableBullets.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        // availableBullets.Add(bullet);
        return shipItemParam;
    }
```

//Bullet class - interact method

```
    public override void Interact(Param.Param interactParam)
    {
        if(interactParam is ShipInteractBullet)
        {
            if((interactParam as ShipInteractBullet).ShipReasonToInteract == ShipEnum.FIRE)
            {
                this.Position.Y = (interactParam as ShipInteractBullet).Position.Y + 0;
                this.Position.X = (interactParam as ShipInteractBullet).Position.X + 33;
                fired = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code, or at least the relevant parts. Note that this will automatically publish the section(s) of code under a Creative Commons license or something similar. if this concerns you, you should try a more private method of gaining help.

Comment: PS-- The sprite might not even need an instance of the world, as long as YOU have one; it depends on the language (which you should add to the tags)

Comment: I use c# for my game. And I really do have the basics of the game nothing special. My ship can move with arrows, that is all I have made for now. So my question is still, how can I drop an item to the world?

Comment: Can I see your code or are you keeping it a secret? ;)

Comment: Can you please tell me what part I should upload? The sprite class? Because my sprite doesnt have a weapon at this moment, it creates ammo and shoots it. So I still have the build the part I asked in this question. Do you want me to send you my project if you want to check it out?

Comment: I added some code mate !

Comment: Sorry, I've been on vacation. I'll check this out in a sec.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create an arrayList or similar of `droppedItem`s and simply add the gun to that list with the sprite's current x and y, then in your draw method, draw the gun on the ground. Also, when the sprite drops it, set a boolean variable in the sprite (`hasWeapon` or something) to false and check if it's true before creating a bullet.

Comment: Seeing as it's been a week, you could just send the project to me and I'd try to implement this myself (never done c# before, but programming experience and Google can solve most problems).

Comment: Thanks mate. I asked my teacher about this and he told me to create a global "spawner class" which has the World object in him. So the sprite can say spawner.Drop(item), and in spawner class the drop methode will call the spawn method from world, world.drop(item) now the world got the item. But I still doubt if this can be good, because giving the world to a class seems a little bit weird to me ...

Comment: And also, does this seem logical to you? "Ship" got a list of bullets. He fires them by saying ammo.Interact(enum reason). Ammo will look if the enum is "bullet_fired" then it will react by setting a bool to true so draw and move is allowed. Now we send the ammo back to the world because Ship doesnt have the ammo anymore and add it too the list in world. So from now it moves on it's own and is in the world, so the "ship" isnt the owner of the object anymore. Do you think programming it like that is good/OOP?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Why can't you do the same thing with bullets?

Comment: I always have big doubts about the smallest things that is why I ask people before I do things like this. But I can indeed use it also  for bullets and other objects. Thanks for your help man, I appreciate it ! : ) I will go further programming and if I have more questions can I ask you about it ? Because I find it sometimes hard to make good decisions because there are 1000 ways of doing things.

Comment: *weapons, not bullets, oops. If you'd like any more help, I'd be glad to help you over at [my helpdesk chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138629/feathercrowns-helpdesk). Just keep in mind I might not be there when you are.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help!